# Parallel Tasks In Windows Services

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, windows-services, async-await

I have a Windows Service which kicks off a function on a timer.  The function queries a database for new records and then calls a web service for each new record it finds.

There is now a requirement that this service does this for multiple databases at each interval.

The service currently looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace MiManager.TicketLogger {

  public partial class TicketLogger : ServiceBase {

    private TicketLoggerSettings _settings;
    private List<DbConnectionSettings> _connections;

    public TicketLogger() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {

      var helpers = new MiManager.TicketLogger.Helpers();
      _settings = helpers.GetTicketLoggerSettings();
      _connections = helpers.GetDbConnectionSettings();

      if (_settings.LogVerbose == true) evlgTicketLogger.WriteEntry("Registry entries obtained", EventLogEntryType.Information, 100);
      tmrTicketLogger.Interval = _settings.ServiceInterval;
      tmrTicketLogger.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
      tmrTicketLogger.Enabled = true;
      tmrTicketLogger.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {
      tmrTicketLogger.Stop();
      tmrTicketLogger.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(Object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
      try {
        tmrTicketLogger.Stop();

        Core core = new MiManager.TicketLogger.Core();
        List<Message> messages = core.LogTickets(_settings);
        foreach (var message in messages) {
          evlgTicketLogger.WriteEntry(message.Text, message.EntryType, message.ErrorCode);
        }
        if (_settings.LogVerbose == true) {
          evlgTicketLogger.WriteEntry("Ticket logging complete", EventLogEntryType.Information, 101);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        evlgTicketLogger.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error, 400);
      }
      finally {
        tmrTicketLogger.Start();
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Now I need to adjust the service to fetch multiple connection strings and call the LogTickets function in the TimerElapsed function for each db connection.

What is the current recommended way of doing this in a Windows Service?

In a previous project many years ago I manually created a new thread for each connection I wanted to process but I'm sure there's a better way now?

Is it a good use case for Async/Await?  If I do that do all the methods in the Core class have to be async as well?

Would it be better to use something like Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: You're not showing the where you use `_connections` or how the records are currently fetched.

Comment: The internal EF-based repository class has helper classes to fetch it's own connection string from the registry. This will have to change as I'll need to detect all the required connection details and iterate over them instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server side, `async` methods give you scalability. However, it sounds like your service doesn't need to scale much, so `async` wouldn't really give you any advantage.

> Would it be better to use something like Parallel.ForEach?

If your existing code is synchronous (and you don't need the scalability that `async` would give you), then that's fine. Your service *would* be less resource-intensive (and probably slightly faster) if you change everything to `async` - but that would require quite a bit of code changes for (AFAICS) little benefit.

If you do want to explore `async` code in a Win32 service, I recommend creating a single main thread using my [`AsyncContextThread` type](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext&referringTitle=Documentation). As long as your `async` code is properly asynchronous (e.g., using [EF6 for asynchronous DB calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx) and [`HttpClient` for asynchronous web calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx)), then you should only need the one thread.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I think I may explore the Parallel.ForEach route first, it's probably only going to have to handle two or three connections per interval so it's not having to scale too much.

Comment: @Stephen, do you have any examples of using your AsyncContextThread type in a Windows service? I've read up on it but haven't quite been able to connect the dots. I have a service that I think could benefit tremendously from running its large number of I/O-intensive tasks without tying up threads. Thanks!

Comment: @ToddMenier: I don't, actually. But I do have [some posts on managed services](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/managed-services-roundup.html) that may help you out. If it's not clear, just post a question and folks will take a look.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks, I've posted a detailed question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585493/calling-async-methods-from-a-windows-service), hoping you might chime in as you really seem to be an expert in this area!

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on the sophistication needs of your solution, how you want to handle your data and what is your current .NET framework version because there are many ways to do this.

You can do something like this where HandleConnection is your function for handling the connection:

```
var parallelTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(_connections, connection => HandleConnection(connection)));
```

I would recommend using a few minutes to read up on parallelism, new async/await features in .NET 4.5 and tasks on MSDN. There are many different continuation options that can be used with tasks. Explore what suits your needs.

[Data Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

[Task Factories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519.aspx)