# Best way to do a task looping in Windows Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a method that send some SMS to our customers that look like below:

```
public void ProccessSmsQueue()
{
   SmsDbContext context = new SmsDbContext();
   ISmsProvider provider = new ZenviaProvider();
   SmsManager manager = new SmsManager(context, provider);

   try
   {
      manager.ProcessQueue();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
   }
   finally
   {
      context.Dispose();
   }
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork).ContinueWith( ??? )
}
```

### So, I have some issues:

1. I don´t know how long it takes for the method run;
2. The method can throw exceptions, that I want to write on EventLog
3. I want to run this method in loop, every 10 min, **but only after last execution finish.**

How I can achieve this? I thought about using `ContinueWith()`, but I still have questions on how to build the entire logic.

Comment: Why do you want to do it using a `Task` at all? Why not just use a `Timer`?

Comment: Using a timer, I would have to control the start and stop each time the event was fired. I thought of using this solution, but did not seem the most elegant.

Comment: What about simply using a loop?

Comment: Because it will run synchronously. I need a mix of async/sync.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should have an async method that accepts a `CancellationToken` so it knows when to stop, calls `ProccessSmsQueue` in a `try-catch` block and uses `Task.Delay` to asynchronously wait until the next time it needs to run:

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            ProccessSmsQueue();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), token);
    }
}
```

You can call this method when your application starts and `Task.Wait` the returned task before existing so you know it completes and has no exceptions:

```
private Task _proccessSmsQueueTask;
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _proccessSmsQueueTask = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token));
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    try
    {
        _proccessSmsQueueTask.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle exeption
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice! How I could start the Task in this scenario under a Windows Service?

Comment: @GuFigueiredo Start it when the service loads and wait for it when it closes.

Comment: The OnStop method on the WinService is not async (cannot use await). If I just cancel the token it will work or I can do this in  another way? (when i use await _task, i receive: 'The await operator can only be used in a method marked with async modifier')

Comment: @GuFigueiredo This is one of the few cases where it's ok to block synchronously on an async operation. Use `Task.Wait`.

Comment: Interesting. So, in this scenario, the delay will only run when the ProcessQueue() finishes? I don´t wanna two or more "ProccessQueues" run at same time.

Comment: you solution worked fine. But when I try to start the service with a big queue, the service deadlock while loading. I receive a "Timeout" message. I think things are happening synchronously. Any ideas?

Comment: @GuFigueiredo yes, an async method run synchronously until an `await` is reached which in your case means it runs `ProccessSmsQueue` once. You can solve that by offloading that work to a `ThreadPool` thread with `Task.Run`. I updated the answer.

Comment: What happens if we put `await DoWorkAsync(_cts.Token)` instead of `Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(_cts.Token));` in the OnStart method ?

Comment: @juzamn `OnStart` returns `void` so it would be an `async void` method which you should only use for event handlers.

Comment: @juzamn when starting the process, it would hang if it takes too long to get to the first await. which is where `Task.Run` helps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20585750/665879) has helpful information aswell

Comment: @i3arnon is _cts a typo? I think it should be _cancellationTokenSource

Comment: @SimplyInk fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Worker Class that I have used in Windows Services. It supports stopping in a 'clean' way by using a lock.
You just have to add your code in DoWork, set your timer in the StartTimerAndWork method (in milliseconds), and use this class in your service.

```
public class TempWorker
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        private Thread _thread = null;

        private object _workerStopRequestedLock = new object();
        private bool _workerStopRequested = false;

        private object _loopInProgressLock = new object();
        private bool _loopInProgress = false;

        bool LoopInProgress
        {
            get
            {
                bool rez = true;

                lock (_loopInProgressLock)
                    rez = _loopInProgress;

                return rez;
            }
            set
            {
                lock (_loopInProgressLock)
                    _loopInProgress = value;
            }
        }

        #region constructors
        public TempWorker()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods
        public void StartWorker()
        {
            lock (_workerStopRequestedLock)
            {
                this._workerStopRequested = false;
            }
            _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartTimerAndWork));
            _thread.Start();
        }
        public void StopWorker()
        {
            if (this._thread == null)
                return;

            lock (_workerStopRequestedLock)
                this._workerStopRequested = true;

            int iter = 0;
            while (LoopInProgress)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                iter++;

                if (iter == 60)
                {
                    _thread.Abort();
                }
            }

            //if (!_thread.Join(60000))
            //    _thread.Abort();

        }
        #endregion


        #region private methods

        private void StartTimerAndWork()
        {
            this._timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            this._timer.Interval = 10000;//milliseconds
            this._timer.Enabled = true;
            this._timer.Start();

        }


        #endregion


        #region event handlers
        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!LoopInProgress)
            {
                lock (_workerStopRequestedLock)
                {
                    if (this._workerStopRequested)
                    {
                        this._timer.Stop();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                DoWork();

            }
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            try
            {
                this.LoopInProgress = true;

                //DO WORK HERE

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //LOG EXCEPTION HERE
            }
            finally
            {
                this.LoopInProgress = false;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```