# Async thread body loop, It just works, but how?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have just tested something that I was sure would fail miserably, but to my surprise,  it worked flawlessly, and proves to myself that I am still quite mystified by how `async-await` works.

I created a thread, passing an `async void` delegate as the thread's body.
Here's an oversimplification of my code:

```
var thread = new Thread( async () => {
   while( true ) {
      await SomeLengthyTask();
      ...
   }
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

The thing is that as far as I understand, when the execution hits the `await` keyword, there is an implicit return from the method, in this case the body of the looping thread, while the rest of the code is wrapped in a callback continuation.

Because of this fact, I was pretty sure that the thread would terminate as soon as the `await` yielded execution, but that's not the case!

**Does anybody know how this magic is actually implemented?** Is the `async` functionality stripped down and the `async` waits synchronously or is there some black magic being done by the CLR that enables it to resume a thread that has yielded because of an `await`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thread is indeed terminated very quickly.

But since the `Thread` constructor doesn't accept an `async` lambda what you got there is an `async void` delegate.

The original thread will end and the continuation (the rest after the `await`) will be posted to the `ThreadPool` and eventually run on another thread.

You can test that by checking the thread id:

```
var thread = new Thread(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await SomeLengthyTask();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
3
5
5
...
5
```

To make the example simpler let's assume you have this `Run` method:

```
void Run(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```

And you call it with your `async` delegate

```
Run(async () => 
{
    while(true) 
    {
      await SomeLengthyTask();
      ...
    }
});
```

The execution of `Run` will complete almost immediately when it reaches the first `await` and returns. The rest of the `async` delegate will continue on the `ThreadPool` with another thread.

---

Generally, each time you reach an `await` in the execution of an `async` method the thread is lost and the continuation (the rest after the awaited task completes) will be posted to the ThreadPool (unless if there's a SynchronizationContext present, like in the UI thread). It may be that it execution will be on the same thread (as in my example with 5) but it also may not.

In your case the thread you create explicitly isn't part of the `ThreadPool` so it will definitely be terminated and the rest will run on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for the correct clarification between lambda and delegate, I edited my question accordingly.  So, to understand,  what the CLR is actually doing is simply preventing the Join() of the original thread to take place?

Comment: @BlueStrat No, it does takes place. That's actually why I added a `Console.ReadLine` in my example. Without it my console application ends before reaching the interesting part.

Comment: @BlueStrat There's nothing special being done to Thread here. `async` methods just don't run on the same thread. They may do that, but as long as there isn't a SynchronizationContext they run each synchronous part on the ThreadPool

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the insight - I guess that it is a very expensive way of maintaining a thread loop  ;)

Comment: @BlueStrat If you use `Task.Run` instead of creating your own thread it can actually be very scalable. It depends on how `async` are the contents of your `while`. If you do something and wait for a minute and do it again etc. it's much better than waiting synchronously. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27189890/885318

Comment: @BlueStrat Actually, it's a pretty common pattern that works rather well. The main question is whether it makes sense to `await` in the first place - if you're doing some I/O or `Task.Delay` or something like that, it should dwarf the overhead of scheduling the thread pool work items. But it's completely useless to create the thread - just use `Task.Run`. It's used for stuff like main connection accept loops in network servers - `async void` method that has `while (true) { var s = await listener.AcceptAsync(); HandleAcceptAsync(s); }` (`HandleAcceptAsync` also being `async void` method).

Comment: @BlueStrat If you want to keep track of the top level (`while (true)`) task, just have it be an `async Task` method - don't `await` on that task, just keep it around. Then you can use e.g. `Task.IsCompleted` to see if it's still running, or something like `Task.Wait` to prevent the application from exiting while the loop is still running (a pretty common pattern in console applications) - be careful with that, though; I'd only use it for the top-level `while (true)` loop.