# Why doesn't the code wait for the loop to complete in "wait"?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
Thread ThreadWindow = new Thread(async () =>
{
    WindowWPF windowWPF = new WindowWPF();
    windowWPF.Show();
    
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //code
        }
    });
    
    //code works when it shouldn't be available
});
```

For some reason, the compiler suggests changing the last line to me: `});` in `}){};` what is this for?

The idea is to display the loading window and work with the data in parallel, after which the window should close.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Async thread body loop, It just works, but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044846/async-thread-body-loop-it-just-works-but-how) In short, passing an async delegate to the `Thread` constructor is a bug. It results in an `async void` method, which is almost certainly [not what you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: Also be aware that interacting with UI elements form any other thread than the UI thread, is not allowed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, I'll try something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not, as soon as `await` is hit, an incomplete `Task` will be returned and the job within `await` will be returned as a `future` callback if it's a bit long running job.

As you have made `while(true)` making the piece of code to execute infinitely, assuming that you are trying to do `call and forget way`, If so then don't use `await`. Also, Instead of you creating `new Thread`, try making use of `Task` as below

```
var task = new Task(() => MyLongRunningMethod(),
                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
task.Start();
```