# Repeat a task (TPL) in windows service, using ContinueWith

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I have a windows service (written in C#) that use the task parallel library dll to perform some parallel tasks (5 tasks a time)
After the tasks are executed once I would like to repeat the same tasks on an on going basis (hourly). Call the QueuePeek method
Do I use a timer or a counter like I have setup in the code snippet below?

I am using a counter to set up the tasks, once I reach five I exit the loop, but I also use a .ContinueWith to decrement the counter, so my thought is that the counter value would be below 5 hence the loop would continue. But my ContinueWith seems to be executing on the main thread and the loop then exits.
The call to DecrementCounter using the ContinueWith does not seem to work

FYI : The Importer class is to load some libraries using MEF and do the work

This is my code sample:

```
    private void QueuePeek()
    {            
        var list = SetUpJobs();

        while (taskCounter < 5)
        {
            int j = taskCounter;

            Task task = null;
            task = new Task(() =>
            {
                DoLoad(j);                                        
            });               

            taskCounter += 1;
            tasks[j] = task;
            task.ContinueWith((t) => DecrementTaskCounter());
            task.Start();
            ds.SetJobStatus(1);                               
        }            
        if (taskCounter == 0)
           Console.WriteLine("Completed all tasks.");
    }       

    private void DoLoad(int i)
    {
        ILoader loader;

    DataService.DataService ds = new DataService.DataService();

    Dictionary<int, dynamic> results = ds.AssignRequest(i);

    var data = results.Where(x => x.Key == 2).First();
    int loaderId = (int)data.Value;

    Importer imp = new Importer();

    loader = imp.Run(GetLoaderType(loaderId));

    LoaderProcessor lp = new LoaderProcessor(loader);

    lp.ExecuteLoader();
    }

    private void DecrementTaskCounter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Decrementing task counter with threadId: {0}",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) );
        taskCounter--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues with your code that can potentially lead to some hard to track-down bugs. First, if using a counter that all of the tasks can potentially be reading and writing to at the same time, try using Interlocked. For example:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _taskCounter); // or Interlocked.Decrement(ref _taskCounter);
```

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, I think what you want to do is to use a timer that you re-schedule after each group of tasks is finished.

```
public class Worker
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private int _timeUntilNextCall = 3600000;

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(QueuePeek), null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    private void QueuePeek(object state)
    {
        int numberOfTasks = 5;

        Task[] tasks = new Task[numberOfTasks];
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = new Task(() =>
            {
                DoLoad();
            });
            tasks[i].Start();
        }

        // When all tasks are complete, set to run this method again in x milliseconds
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (t) => { _timer.Change(_timeUntilNextCall, Timeout.Infinite); });
    }

    private void DoLoad() { }
}
```

Comment: birken
thanks for your suggestions, especially for the counter. 
I like the outline you have suggested above.
Also found a link that had another example with task.delay
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189750/best-way-to-do-a-task-looping-in-windows-service?rq=1

Comment: Looks like the Task.Delay uses the System.Threading.Timer under the hood to implement the delay. The added benefit of a built-in cancellation functionality seems like a good reason to use Task.Delay. Make sure you've got good exception handling [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) when using tasks, since it can be a little tricky.