# TPL C# Windows Service - anything wrong?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, task-parallel-library

Hi writing Windows service with TPL and the requirement is 
Windows service should run every few mins or few seconds and execute the 4 tasks in parallel. I have implemented following code but got a doubt like

```
Task[] taskRunners = new Task[Utility.conTaskRunners];

        Log("Stating Initiate Tasks::" + DateTime.Now);

        Log("Calling InitiateTaskRunner Tasks::" + DateTime.Now);

        taskRunners[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InitiateTaskRunner());
        taskRunners[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ScanTaskRunner());
        taskRunners[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConvertTaskRunner());
        taskRunners[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConvertedScanRunner());
        Task.WaitAll(taskRunners);
        Thread.Sleep(12000);

        InitiateTasks();
```

InitiateTaskRunner look like below

```
 public void InitiateTaskRunner()
    {
        Log("Begening InitiateTaskRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);           
        string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Utility.inputPath);
        if (subDirs.Length > 0) //files eixsts go and process it
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(subDirs, dir =>
            {
                InitiateTaskWorker(dir);
            });
        }           
        //BEFORE I SET signal SHOULD this wait as above is PARALLEL.FOREACH?
        _waitOnOne.Set(); //set signal for successor after finish
        Log("Ending InitiateTaskRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Similarly other 3 TaskRunnerswill be; basically each task runner will call TaskWorker for each sub directory and process files asynchonously and eatch TASK Runner and Each Task Worker will be independent and concurrent. The files from one taskWorker to another Task worker locationwill be moved soon after TaskWorker done its work with files and next taskworker will pickup but no trigger from one task worker to another task worker.

The problem with this approach is, sometimes 2, 3, and 4 task runners may exit without doing anything while first task runner still processing and pushing to taskrunner#2 location and so on. and the files from task runners location 2,3,4 will be processed in next iteration.

is there any better desgin for this? and any help regading to exception handling in TPL will be great.

```
public void ScanTaskRunner()
    {
        Log("Begening ScanTaskRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);            
        string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Utility.scanPath);
        if (subDirs.Length > 0)  //files exists so proceed
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(subDirs, dir =>
            {
                ScanTaskWorker(dir, false);
            });
        }
        else //no files hence wait for prcedent TASK to complete
        {
            _waitOnOne.WaitOne();
            Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetDirectories(Utility.scanPath), dir =>
            {
                ScanTaskWorker(dir, false);
            });
        }
        _waitOnTwo.Set(); //Go successor if waiting for this
        Log("Ending ScanTaskRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
    }
public void ConvertTaskRunner()
    {
       Log("Begening ConvertTasktRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
        string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Utility.convertPath);
        if (subDirs.Length > 0)  //files exists so process as usual
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(subDirs, dir =>
            {
                ConvertTaskWorker(dir);
            });
        }
        else  //no files hence wait for precedent TASK to complete
        {
            _waitOnTwo.WaitOne();
            Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetDirectories(Utility.scanPath), dir =>
            {
                ScanTaskWorker(dir, false);
            });
        }
        _waitOnThree.Set();  //Successor is good to go if waiting
        Log("Ending ConvertTasktRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
    }
 public void ConvertedScanRunner()
    {
        Log("Begening ConvertedScanRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
        string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Utility.convrtedScanPath);
        if (subDirs.Length > 0)  //files avaiable process as usual
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(subDirs, dir =>
            {
                ConvertedScanTaskWorker(dir);
            });
        }
        else  //no files wait until precendent TASK completes
        {
            _waitOnThree.WaitOne();
            Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetDirectories(Utility.scanPath), dir =>
            {
                ScanTaskWorker(dir, false);
            });
        }
        Log("Ending ConvertedScanRunner ::" + DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Best way to do a task looping in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189750/best-way-to-do-a-task-looping-in-windows-service?rq=1) for a good way to kick-start your tasks and keep them going.

As far as exception handling and such, you'll probably want to wait on all of the tasks you have running and catch and handle the `AggregateException`. Any tasks that threw an exception will have `IsFaulted` true. Use the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in each task to cooperate with everyone else and partake in being cancelled. Those tasks that cooperated will have their `IsCanceled` property true.

```
    public void Run(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        _cts = cts;
        Task[] tasks = new Task[4];

        try
        {
            tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PhaseOne(), cts.Token);
            tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PhaseTwo(), cts.Token);
            tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PhaseThree(), cts.Token);
            tasks[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PhaseFour(), cts.Token);

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions
            foreach(Exception inner in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }

        if (tasks.Any(t => t.IsFaulted))
        {
            // do something
        }
        if (tasks.Any(t => t.IsCanceled))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

As for your issue of keeping the tasks in sync and knowing when to process files or when another phase has finished, you can use an [EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) (although there are any number of ways you can do it). The wait handle might be a little slower than some other alternatives (like a spin lock) since it goes to the kernel, but for waiting on file processing it might be a good idea to use it.

The code here shows what PhaseTwo might look like. PhaseOne would look essentially the same, but you'd be using a wait handle for one, different processing delegate, etc.

```
    private EventWaitHandle _waitOnTwo = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    public void PhaseTwo()
    {
        try
        {
            string phaseTwoDir = "C:\\PhaseTwo";
            string phaseThreeDir = "C:\\PhaseThree";

            Action<string> processFiles = new Action<string>((file) => { File.Move(file, Path.Combine(phaseThreeDir, Path.GetFileName(file))); _waitOnTwo.Set(); });
            Func<bool> continueCondition = new Func<bool>(() => { return (Directory.GetFiles(phaseTwoDir).Count() > 0 || _waitOnOne.WaitOne(60000)); });

            // process files
            Process(phaseTwoDir, processFiles, continueCondition);
        }
        finally
        {
            _waitOnTwo.Set();
        }
    }

    private void Process(string directory, Action<string> processFileWork, Func<bool> continueCondition)
    {
        while (continueCondition())
        {
            foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory))
            {
                // if canceled, throw
                _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                // process file
                processFileWork(file);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks briken, gave some idea on exception handling will try to implement and see; on the other hand on processing Phase()1, 2 ,3 ,4 yet to figure out what to do. WaitOne may not correctly suite as the situation is, when service started there may be files in phase1,2,3,4 locations hence should be processed concurrently and also yes, phase1 move the files to phase2 as and when processed; phase2 will move files to 3 as and when processed. moreover waitOne is pretty much SYNC process if I understood correctly, pls correct if I am wrong.

Comment: No that's right. The event wait handle is typically used for that. I use it here to essentially give up the thread in each loop iteration (if you place it in a loop in phase2) instead of continuously looping and evaluating the loop condition (since I/O and file processing might take a while). Using the loop idea, you can just have each phase run in a loop, fishing it's own directory for files to process. Then when each phase finishes (in order), they can signal to the others they are done with a simple bool.

Comment: Okay, then something like, main thread will run 4 pahses in parallel and wait for all tasks to complete as it is now and then each subtask will check files existance before issues Parallel.ForEach file, if no files found then cant it wait for precedent task SET? in that case phase2 will run its first run as usual if files are there else wait for pahse1 to give signal? pls clarify thanks

Comment: That first part is right. As well as each sub-task checking for files in the directory. I updated the code to show better what I mean. Hopefully it helps. It relies on a timeout (in my code it's one minute) to ultimately decide when to quit. You may want to add some more logic if you want to know exactly when the previous phase ended, then maybe process the files one last time.

Comment: Hi Birken, to proceed further, i have made changes as per my understanding and updated the original post..can you pls check once? I hope it should be okay with WaitOne machanisim that I have done.

Comment: Looks like that is close. I would probably add a timeout value in those waits. Also, I think, based on what you want, you need to put a loop in each of those methods and use the wait handle to not only signal when the phase is done but also to signal when processing one file is done. Otherwise, you may as well just run each phase in series (i.e., not in parallel tasks). I'd try it without the Parallel.Foreach and just a foreach first to get that working. Then, if you want to try and make it faster, add in the parallel and see if all still works as expected and faster.

Comment: got into atleast some shape. basically I removed the "else" part before waiting every phase, I made all phases start concurrently and process if there are files else just wait for previous phase to finish[ that should be okay]. now, you are asking me to add time into WaitOne method whihc did not uunderstand need of it. and also,the cancellation of Task will happen only if Windows service is stopped abruptly? is that the reason we added in main thread isFaulted or isCancelled? I will mark it answer anyway as you helped to get into a shape but would be great if you can answer these pls.

Comment: The timeout is not something you need the way your code is setup. I just generally like to have a timeout to ensure it will finish. I added the IsFaulted and IsCancelled code just to show you some ways you can check those if you want. Put `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in your loops and `Task.WaitAll` will throw an `AggregateException`. You can handle it there. Be sure to wrap that WaitAll in a try-catch block. Read up on exception handling for tasks because you want to make sure you get it right.