# Async Await top level handling

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have about 10 SQL tables that I need to extract data, process, and then insert that data into another table. I don't want to do them all in parallel, but I would like to make use of all the IO time.

I have a function:

```
    public async Task PromoteAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HTTransDB transactions = new HTTransDB())
            using (ZImportMaster importMaster = new ZImportMaster())
            using (ZMasterAddress masterAddress = new ZMasterAddress())
            {
                // Select out non error rows
                DataTable dt = await HTTransDB.GetValidRowsAsync(this.TableConfig.BatchID, this.TableConfig.SourceTableName);


                // Do stuff

                // insert data
                using (HTTransDB transactionsDB = new HTTransDB())
                {
                    int result = await transactionDB.BulkCopyAsync(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log exception and re-throw
        }
    }
```

I run this function in a foreach loop for each table:

```
    public async Task PromoteLoad()
    {
        // Load each batch
        foreach (var table in this.Tables)
        {
            await table.PromoteAsync();
        }
    }
```

My question is, how do I call this function from a non Async method? `Task.Run`? I don't want to start new threads, I just want the process to keep running while waiting for IO.

Comment: Have you tried  `PromoteLoad()` ?

Comment: What type of application is it?  Is it a console app? A web app? A WPF/WinForms app?  What other work do you expect to happen while the IO work happens, and on which thread?  Do you have more code that needs to execute after the async work completes?

Comment: This is running in a window service that reads off a queue. I would just like to go on to the next table if the last one is waiting for io.

Comment: Maybe some ideas from this thread can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585493/calling-async-methods-from-a-windows-service

Answer (score 1):

You can start the asynchronous work by just invoking the method:

```
var promoteTask = PromoteAsync();
```

Note that the returned task represents the execution of that method.